# Neovim deoplete use python3 as default

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to use deoplete with neovim using python3 as default.

I am trying to set up deoplete for neovim supported with deoplete-deji. I have installed both correctly, and it works as expected, but only for python 2. I have confirmed this by running `sys.version_info` which shows python2.

Things i have done so far are:

- installed the plugins.

  - zchee/deoplete-jedi
  - Shougo/deoplete.nvim
- installed neovim using `pip` and `pip3`

set the following deoplete configurations:

```
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
let g:deoplete#file#enable_buffer_path = 1
let g:deoplete#enable_smart_case = 1
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
let g:deoplete#file#enable_buffer_path = 1
let g:deoplete#enable_smart_case = 1
```

When i used `let g:loaded_python_provider = 1`, everything works as expected, but when i change it to `let g:loaded_python3_provider = 1`, i am getting `Vim(let):E117: Unknown function: provider#python3#Prog` when running `UpdateRemotePlugins`

I am a bit opposed to creating an alias, because i want python to point to python2

Long story short, trying to make python3 default for everything in neovim including deoplete and jedi
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through the docs, deoplete jedi searches for `python` in PATH. Setting `g:deoplete#sources#jedi#python_path = 'python3'` is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing this kind of problem, so, in the error messages I saw something related with gcc, then I started searching for the development packs for my linux distro (voidlinux). The solution came when I installed:

```
python3-pip python3-devel python-devel base-devel xclip neovim
```

And the neovim library to python3 and python3

```
sudo pip install neovim
sudo pip3 install neovim
```

All this was only possible due to the command:

```
:checkhealt
```

The deoplate plugin website has also a recommendation:

```
:UpdateRemotePlugins
```